# How to open child forms positioned within MDI parent in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, mdichild

How do we arrange child forms in a parent MDI window? I'm able to call and display a child form from a menu on the parent, but the child pops up outside the parent - I want it to actually be inside the parent. I've checked in C# and VB.Net solutions but they all say pretty much the same, i.e. try to access LayoutMDI, such as here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fhk181.aspx

The problem is, where do I access this? When I'm in the code of my MDI parent, `Me.LayoutMdi` is not recognized. In which part of the application do I put the `Me.LayoutMDI` code?

### Edit

The `Me.LayoutMDI` code worked in the parent after all. I'd been trying for a while but don't know where I was going wrong.

However, the child continues to pop up out of the parent. Here's an image of how that happens. The broader form in the back is the parent, and the one with the gridview and two buttons is the new child that popped up. I want it to pop up "Docked" within the parent.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the sample I posted?, from reading all the comments below and the advice of the other members, it sounds like your using an ordinary form and not an MDI form OR the MDICHILD property is not set in your CHILD form.

Answer (score 4):

If your form is "outside" the MDI parent, then you most likely didn't set the MdiParent property:

```
Dim f As New Form
f.MdiParent = Me
f.Show()
```

Me, in this example, is a form that has `IsMdiContainer = True` so that it can host child forms.

For re-arranging the child form layout, you just call the method from your MdiContainer form:

```
Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade)
```

The MdiLayout enum also has tiling and arrange icons values.

Comment: Actually I am using that code you mentioned. But children are still appearing outside the window. What I did to come around this was to just make a panel and put the child form's elements on that panel, and fix that panel in the parent window. But I this is no the right way to do it. I checked for some "Dock" property on forms, but can't find one. What's missing?

Comment: @user961627 We might have to see an image of what you are describing.  A form that has its MdiParent property set can't be "outside" of it.  As far as the LayoutMdi method, if you can't find that method, than you have to make sure that your "Me" object is, in fact, a form and not a control.

Comment: @user961627 Obviously, don't put your forms inside of panels.

Comment: I know :( Anyway I've updated the question to add an image so you can see where the new child shows up.

Comment: @user961627 Either your parent form is not configured with `IsMdiContainer = True` or you are not setting the ChildForm.MdiParent to the parent form.  You also don't "dock" the child form inside the parent.  If you want it to fill the parent space, you just call `ChildForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized.`

Comment: I'm doing both. In fact, I used Project > Add Windows Form > MDI Parent Form when I made the new form.

Comment: @user961627 Well, double check the IsMdiContainer property for the form in the property grid.  Your parent form doesn't look like an MDI parent because I don't see any Minimize / Maximize buttons for the child form.  It's that or you have a panel control dock-filled in the parent, in which case, that would be wrong, too.

Answer (score 2):

Dont set MDI Child property from MDIForm

In Chileform Load event give the below code

```
    Dim l As Single = (MDIForm1.ClientSize.Width - Me.Width) / 2
    Dim t As Single = ((MDIForm1.ClientSize.Height - Me.Height) / 2) - 30
    Me.SetBounds(l, t, Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Me.MdiParent = MDIForm1
```

end

try this code

Answer (score 2):

You will want to set the `MdiParent` property of your new form to the name of the MDI parent form, as follows:

```
dim form as new yourform
form.show()
form.MdiParent = nameParent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Private Sub FileMenu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) handles FileMenu.Click

    Form1.MdiParent = Me
    Form1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a button on mdi parent and add this code' to set your mdi child inside the mdi parent. change the yourchildformname to your MDI Child's form name and see if this works.

```
    Dim NewMDIChild As New yourchildformname()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    NewMDIChild.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and.....

1 - change the name of the MENU as in my sample the menuitem was called 'Form7ToolStripMenuItem_Click'

2 - make SURE to paste it into an MDIFORM and not just a basic FORM

Then let me know if the CHILD form still shows OUTSIDE the parent form

```
Private Sub Form7ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Form7ToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim NewForm As System.Windows.Forms.Form
    NewForm = New System.Windows.Forms.Form
    'USE THE NEXT LINE - to add an existing CUSTOM form you already have
    'NewForm = Form7                         
    NewForm.Width = 400
    NewForm.Height = 250
    NewForm.MdiParent = Me
    NewForm.Text = "CAPTION"
    NewForm.Show()
    DockChildForm(NewForm, "left")          'dock left
    'DockChildForm(NewForm, "right")         'dock right
    'DockChildForm(NewForm, "top")           'dock top
    'DockChildForm(NewForm, "bottom")        'doc bottom
    'DockChildForm(NewForm, "full")          'fill the client area (maximise the child INSIDE the parent)
    'DockChildForm(NewForm, "Anything-Else") 'center the form

End Sub

Private Sub DockChildForm(ByRef Form2Dock As Form, ByVal Position As String)

    Dim XYpoint As Point
    Select Case Position
        Case "left"
            Form2Dock.Dock = DockStyle.Left
        Case "top"
            Form2Dock.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        Case "right"
            Form2Dock.Dock = DockStyle.Right
        Case "bottom"
            Form2Dock.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        Case "full"
            Form2Dock.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Case Else
            XYpoint = New Point
            XYpoint.X = ((Me.ClientSize.Width - Form2Dock.Width) / 2)
            XYpoint.Y = ((Me.ClientSize.Height - Form2Dock.Height) / 2)
            Form2Dock.Location = XYpoint
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Making the Child Form's StartPosition Property set to Center Parent. This you can select from the form Properties.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for the solution!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx

I was able to implement the `Child` form inside the parent.

In the Example below `Form2` should change to the name of your child form.
`NewMDIChild.MdiParent=me` is the main form since the control that opens (shows) the child form is the parent or `Me`.

`NewMDIChild.Show()` is your child form since you associated your child form with `Dim NewMDIChild As New Form2()`

```
Protected Sub MDIChildNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem2.Click
   Dim NewMDIChild As New Form2()
   'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
   NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
   'Display the new form.
   NewMDIChild.Show()
End Sub
```

Simple and it works.